# how do i make excel vba move to the next cell in a for loop?

Tags: excel, vba

I have here the code for a Macro that does some data pick and place from one worksheet to another. Right now this code does 90% of what I want it to do. The problem is that if it encounters a source cell that has nothing in it (Hence `Len(cellVal) = 0` and `cellVal = ""` it overwrites the destination cell.

You will see that at the second ElseIf block there is a comment. Right now it does nothign but if the statement evaluates to true, i.e. there is nothing in the source cell, I want Excel to move on to the next source cell WITHOUT modifying the destination cell's contents.

Any ideas on how this might be accomplished?

Franklin

```
For i = 7 To endPointFlash
    Dim cellVal As String
    cellVal = Cells(i, "G")

    If (Len(cellVal)) > 0 Then
        RawData.Activate
    ElseIf (Len(cellVal)) = 0 Or cellVal = "" Then
        ' need to tell excel to do nothing and move to the next cell
    End If

    For j = 1 To endPointRaw
        If cellVal = Mid(Cells(j, "A"), 1, Len(cellVal)) Then
            val2 = Mid(Cells(j, "A"), 1, Len(cellVal))
            val3 = Cells(j, "D")
            Flash.Cells(i, "H").Value = val3
            Exit For
        Else: Flash.Cells(i, "H").Value = 0
        End If
    Next j
Flash.Activate
Next i
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be very clear and explicit I would write this:

```
Dim cellVal As String

For i = 7 To endPointFlash
    cellVal = Flash.Cells(i, "G")

    If Len(cellVal) = 0 Then
        ' Do nothing.
    Else
        For j = 1 To endPointRaw
            If cellVal = Mid(RawData.Cells(j, "A"), 1, Len(cellVal)) Then
                val2 = Mid(RawData.Cells(j, "A"), 1, Len(cellVal))
                val3 = RawData.Cells(j, "D")
                Flash.Cells(i, "H").Value = val3
                Exit For
            Else
                Flash.Cells(i, "H").Value = 0
            End If
        Next j
    End If

Next i
```

Here it's pretty clear to the reader that a cell containing an empty string should result in no action; in all other cases do the following.

Also I don't activate each sheet back and forth. Doing this makes your code go slower (and makes your screen flicker). Instead I identify each call to `Cells` using the proper sheet name. Again this makes it very explicit where you're getting things.

NB: `cellVal = ""` necessarily implies `Len(cellVal)) = 0`, so there's no need to write both in your conditional.

Comment: You were faster by a few minutes it seems :-)

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
For i = 7 To endPointFlash
    Dim cellVal As String
    cellVal = Cells(i, "G")

    If (Len(cellVal)) > 0 Then
        RawData.Activate
    ElseIf (Len(cellVal)) = 0 Or cellVal = "" Then
        ' need to tell excel to do nothing and move to the next cell
    Else
        For j = 1 To endPointRaw
            If cellVal = Mid(Cells(j, "A"), 1, Len(cellVal)) Then
                val2 = Mid(Cells(j, "A"), 1, Len(cellVal))
                val3 = Cells(j, "D")
                Flash.Cells(i, "H").Value = val3
                Exit For
            Else: Flash.Cells(i, "H").Value = 0
            End If
        Next j
    End If

Flash.Activate
Next i
```

Or like this:

```
For i = 7 To endPointFlash
    Dim cellVal As String
    cellVal = Cells(i, "G")

    If (Len(cellVal)) > 0 Then
        RawData.Activate
    ElseIf (Len(cellVal)) = 0 Or cellVal = "" Then
        ' need to tell excel to do nothing and move to the next cell
        Goto NextLoop
    End If

    For j = 1 To endPointRaw
        If cellVal = Mid(Cells(j, "A"), 1, Len(cellVal)) Then
            val2 = Mid(Cells(j, "A"), 1, Len(cellVal))
            val3 = Cells(j, "D")
            Flash.Cells(i, "H").Value = val3
            Exit For
        Else: Flash.Cells(i, "H").Value = 0
        End If
    Next j
NextLoop:
Flash.Activate
Next i
```

Comment: +1 Suggest using the `Mid$` string function rather than `Mid`

Comment: @assylias - Thanks, your quite right, however I was trying to avoid rewriting his code as I was unable to make sense of what he was trying to do.   Mainly which sheets he was intending to work with.  Instead I gave him correct logic and ignored the conditions and other errors.  A bit lazy of me I agree.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this (not sure if your `Flash.Activate` should be executed when the cell is empty - if so move it below the `End If`):

```
Dim cellVal As String

For i = 7 To endPointFlash
    cellVal = Cells(i, "G")

    If cellVal <> "" Then
      RawData.Activate

      For j = 1 To endPointRaw
          If cellVal = Mid(Cells(j, "A"), 1, Len(cellVal)) Then
              val2 = Mid(Cells(j, "A"), 1, Len(cellVal))
              val3 = Cells(j, "D")
              Flash.Cells(i, "H").Value = val3
              Exit For
          Else
              Flash.Cells(i, "H").Value = 0
          End If
      Next j

      Flash.Activate

    End If 'Else cell is empty: do nothing
Next i
```